# Display/Paginate posts/items month by month in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

This thread, I believe, will not require any code samples to make understandable. I am developing an app using Laravel where input values are saved on the database in a daily basis.
To view them in the front page Laravel offers a paginate method which is cool but I want the pagination to display posts or items by month. I hope you get the idea already. Can this be implemented? This is going to be the major feature of this app so I'm really in need of some idea. Ask me if I need to edit the thread and add some code example I have so far. 
Hope this will be useful for a few more newbies out there.

Comment: Are you saying that each page should contain all items for a month and by clicking the pagination link for second month should show all the items for another month ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha, Exactly!